# grep to display all IPs in a text file (linux)

Tags: bash, ip, grep

I'm writing a script to look for a ping from a certian foreign IP, but I am having some trouble understanding how to format my "grep" command.. Inside my text file is the output from "netstat anp" command. In windows, I was able to achieve this with the following command:

```
grep -oP (\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3} inc.txt
```

The output in the text file is formatted as such:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State        
tcp        0      1 172.18.24.12:51699      72.21.91.17:https       FIN_WAIT1    
tcp        0      1 172.18.24.12:55154      71.19.176.223:https     FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 172.18.24.12:59926      173.194.46.89:http      FIN_WAIT1
```

(I plan of filtering the local address out). But I can't seem to figure out how I should be formatting this command for my bash script. I don't suppose somebody here can help me out with this? Help is always appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste an example of the output of `netstat` in your question? There are loads of different options and it's much easier if we know what you're looking at.

Comment: Yes (sorry) I have updated op.

Comment: maybe something like this works -> grep inc.txt -e ".*(\d{1,3}\.){3}(\d{1,3}).*"

Comment: perl might have a tool it might have an even more up to date regex thing than grep, that might support specifying number ranges.

Comment: -1 You should have shown the error you are getting.. And if you did even basic troubleshooting, you'd have seen that even a simple example like `$ echo 3.4.5.6 | grep -oP (\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3}`  was failing even without all that nestat output.  You should've posted the error e.g. `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`    And you should've stated that you were fine with that regex logically. And since you got a syntax error(which you didn't state), you should've tried a simpler regex like `$ echo 123 | grep -oP (\d)`` and seen the same error. You show zero troubleshooting efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quoting the regex seems to work for me:

```
grep -oP '(\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3}' inc.txt
```

**Edit by barlop-**

Or as Scott gave, slightly more specific  `'(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'`  if you want to make it so it's exactly 4 octets no more no less.

Comment: @user7980, BTW your regex is a bit loose.  It will also match `172.18` or `172.18.24`.  You could probably use `(\d{1,3}\.){4}\d{1,3}` to make it a bit more strict.

Comment: @heavyd: (1) By [some interpretations](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-00#section-2.1.1), “172.18” and “172.18.24” _are_ valid IPv4 addresses – but so are “0x7F.0.0.1”, “10.16777215”, and “2130706433”, so it doesn’t make a lot of sense to try to look for them with a regex. Given that, (2) I believe that you mean `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}`.

Comment: He said "I plan of filtering the local address out)"   You should have mentioned that, e.g. pointing out that yours won't. And since your line is similar to his, you should point out the difference between your line and his `grep -oP (\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3} inc.txt`

Comment: @barlop, I did point out the difference. The only difference is I added quotes to the command line.  And, I may have interpreted what he said incorrectly, but I took it as **I** plan on filtering the local address, as in he is already taking care of that requirement in a different part of his script (I may be wrong).  In either case, I don't think it make the answer not useful, especially since the OP marked it a answering his question.

Comment: yeah your answer's fine..I guess your interpretation was right re number ranges,  it was a very poor question though

Answer (score 0):

A successive discovery method that works from a script or from a shell is this:

For example suppose we are looking for 72.21.95.46

```
grep ' 72\.' netstat.txt will give you all the ip addresses that start with 72.
```

you can then filter that output with subsequent greps to limit the IPs to a family or unique IP:

from the shell you can use "repeat the previous command with bang bang":

```
!! | grep 21\.
```

from a script

```
grep ' 72\.' | grep 21\.
```

and so on.

To get it in one shot just say

```
grep 72.21.95.46 netstat.txt
```

the dots will expand to any single character

if you are flying space shuttles use:

```
grep '72\.21\.95\.46' netstat.txt
```